# Jersey Bean Validation interpreting application/x-www-form-urlencoded as a bean

Tags: java, rest, jersey, javabeans

I am working on a REST service using the Jersey RESTful Web Services framework.

It is required to consume a url encoded form content-type and have it be interpreted/validated as a bean.

```
@POST @Path("put")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@NotNull (message="Couldn't put this bean in the can, sorry")
public Response putABean( @Valid final MrBean bean ){ ... }
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MrBean {

@DecimalMin(value = "18" , message= "value must be at least 18")
@DecimalMax(value = "99" , message= "value must at most be 99")
@NotNull(message = "{null.generic}")
private Long age;

@NotNull(message = "{null.name.first}")
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message = "{null.name.last}")
private String lastName;

@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]{3,9}", message="{invalid.phone}")
@NotNull(message = "{null.generic}")
private String phone;

...

}
```

This is possible when the resource consumes application/json or application/xml , but in the case of application/x-www-form-urlencoded I receive a '415 - Unsupported Media Type' response.

My understanding is that this isn't supported out of the box, and needs a feature registered similar to how it's done here:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to be with bean validation. First thing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not a `MessageBodyReader` for arbitrary types like your `MyBean`. The only types the read can handle is [`Form`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html) and [`MultivaluedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html). So those are the only two type you can have as the body parameter.

But there is another option. The `@BeanParam` annotation allows you to create a bean to combine arbitrary `@XxxParam` annotated elements, like `@FormParam`, `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`, `@HeaderParam`, etc. So if you know the expected keys from the submitted form, you can do something like

```
public class MrBean {

    // validation annotations
    @FormParam("key1")
    private String value1;

    // validation annotations
    @FormParam("key2")
    private String value2;

    // getters setters
}
```

Then you can do

```
public Response putABean( @Valid @BeanParam MrBean bean ){ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful functionality to become aware of. On a related note there's reference for the entire package of annotations here: https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/index.html?javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html